# Aligning points to a grid using skimage's transform.PolynomialTransform.estimate

Tags: python, image, transformation, scikit-image, distortion

Let's say I have a list of points in coordinate form which are supposed to form a perfect grid in reality, but are somewhat distorted (like in the image below). You'll notice that the spacing between the points varies, but I am looking for a way to make this image completely uniform by finding polynomial coefficients to correct for this distortion.

[image]

In my attempts, I've tried using [`skimage`'s `transform` method](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PolynomialTransform) as shown in the line of code below:

```
transform.PolynomialTransform.estimate(original_points, destination_points, 3)
```

There are a few problems with this, however. First and foremost, I don't know the exact format for the points parameter. I've used a list like `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2], ...]` among other formats but it always gives the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

The second problem is that even if I manage to format the points correctly, it doesn't seem like the function returns any polynomial coefficients to actually apply this correction.

What I am asking here is either:

- How do I use the `estimate` function properly to return polynomial correction coefficients (including how to actually input the parameters properly)?
- Alternatively, is there a different function which would be easier to use for this purpose?

So this problem can be reproducible, try using the following points:

```
(0,0), (2,0), (1,1), (0,2), (2,2)
```

And fitting these points to these new points:

```
(0,0), (4,0), (2,3), (0,6), (4,6)
```

Note that I would prefer to be able to obtain 3rd order polynomial coefficients

Comment: Note that if there is actually a better function to use for this purpose, I don't care if it's not inside the skimage package! Anything that works, works.

Answer (score 0):

The input points should be NumPy arrays, not lists:

```py
In [1]: src = np.array([(0,0), (2,0), (1,1), (0,2), (2,2)])                            
In [2]: dst = np.array([(0,0), (4,0), (2,3), (0,6), (4,6)])                            
In [3]: from skimage import transform                                                  
In [4]: p = transform.PolynomialTransform()                                            
In [5]: p.estimate(src, dst, order=3)                                                  
Out[5]: True

In [6]: p.params                                                                       
Out[6]: 
array([[-0.        ,  3.71780989,  1.50088949, -1.85561862, -2.62105008,
        -0.35138037,  0.49835684,  1.68275802, -0.37223298, -0.19953219],
       [-0.        ,  0.85714286,  1.        ,  0.42857143,  0.57142857,
         0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714, -0.14285714,  0.14285714]])
```